# alert on qqe mod by 2 consecutive ascending or descending histogram bars

Tags: pine-script, alerts

how i can create alert on qqe with this condition:

- alert on 2 consecutive ascending or descending histogram bars with signal line above or below the zero level.

like shown on the picture

[image]

```
    //@version=4
//By Glaz, Modified
//
study("QQE MOD")
RSI_Period = input(6, title='RSI Length')
SF = input(5, title='RSI Smoothing')
QQE = input(3, title='Fast QQE Factor')
ThreshHold = input(3, title="Thresh-hold")
//
//
```

// here is the complete qqe indicator [source code if needed](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ewJqDgymQ4qvYTn-mhdvDv0E8hiS78xUVY8Zs3bUULs/edit?usp=sharing)  //

```
//
// Zero cross
QQE2zlong = 0
QQE2zlong := nz(QQE2zlong[1])
QQE2zshort = 0
QQE2zshort := nz(QQE2zshort[1])
QQE2zlong := RSIndex2 >= 50 ? QQE2zlong + 1 : 0
QQE2zshort := RSIndex2 < 50 ? QQE2zshort + 1 : 0
//  

hcolor2 = RsiMa2 - 50 > ThreshHold2 ? color.silver :
   RsiMa2 - 50 < 0 - ThreshHold2 ? color.silver : na
plot(FastAtrRsi2TL - 50, title='QQE Line', color=color.white, transp=0, linewidth=2)
plot(RsiMa2 - 50, color=hcolor2, transp=50, title='Histo2', style=plot.style_columns)

Greenbar1 = RsiMa2 - 50 > ThreshHold2
Greenbar2 = RsiMa - 50 > upper

Redbar1 = RsiMa2 - 50 < 0 - ThreshHold2
Redbar2 = RsiMa - 50 < lower
plot(Greenbar1 and Greenbar2 == 1 ? RsiMa2 - 50 : na, title="QQE Up", style=plot.style_columns, color=#00c3ff, transp=0)
plot(Redbar1 and Redbar2 == 1 ? RsiMa2 - 50 : na, title="QQE Down", style=plot.style_columns, color=#ff0062, transp=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `rising()` and `falling()` functions to figure out if the bars are rising or falling consecutively.

Then use this a condition to your `alert()` or `alertcondition()`.